# Upgrading Ruby (1.9->2) & Rails(3.2->4) for Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, railsinstaller-windows

I'm still new to RoR followed a tutorial and have been developing some apps.
I've installed http://railsinstaller.org/en
For my Windows 7 64-bit operating system.

I'm looking to upgrade from:

Ruby -   1.9.3p392 ->  2.0.0
Rails -  3.2.13    ->  4

Rails installer doesn't have this available.  To Upgrade Ruby, should I download the installer at http://rubyinstaller.org/?   I could download it but how can I properly overwrite my ruby version to ugprade.  Same with Rails 4.  Looking for any pointers to get off in the right direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok , you should really always use something like rvm, at least for development to keep the gems you use in your projects confined.

if you already have an application running, i would recommend you to watch Ryan Bates railscast about it.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4

And Here is a great article from the guys at rails apps that will make everything even clearer, if you are upgrading your app too.

http://railsapps.github.io/updating-rails.html

Hope this helps :D.

Comment: RVM is not available for Windows at this time. Windows has it's own quirks for managing Ruby versions versus a *NIX system.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically three options to get the latest version of Ruby on Windows.

1. Download Ruby 2.0.0 from http://rubyinstaller.org and change the PATH in your windows environment variables.
2. Use [pik](https://github.com/vertiginous/pik) to manage Ruby versions.
3. Uninstall RailsInstaller and try the 3.0.0-alpha version from [Github](https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-windows/releases/tag/3.0.0-alpha.2)

Something to be aware of is that some gems, such as sqlite3, may require manual compilation with Ruby 2.

For Rails 4, the best bet would be to use Bundler in your project and install it that way. RailsInstaller should be Bundler-aware and different versions should not conflict with each other.

Hope that helps and if you have further questions, check out the RailsInstaller Google Group or #railsinstaller on Freenode IRC.

Evan

Comment: Thanks for the information this helped me out. I'm just wondering how do I go about uninstalling the railsinstaller?

Comment: You should be able to uninstall it like any Windows program.