# Ruby: How to update to Ruby 2.1 in windows? (Installed 1.9.3 using Rails Installer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed Ruby 1.9.3, Git, Bundler, Rails 3.2 long ago using RailsInstaller.
It's pretty easy to upgrade Rails, I can just change it in my Rails' Gemfile

But, How can I update ruby? How can I do it?

I find there is a newer version of RailsInstaller, with Ruby 2.1. But it seems just like an installer, not for upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quickest way would be to uninstall the previous version of rails installer, and installing with the new version of rails installer.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18083733/429758 & [How to update ruby in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722703/how-to-update-ruby-in-windows) for more on the same topic.

Comment: I found there is a uninstall.exe in RailsInstaller folder, so I just uninstall it and install the new one.